# How to setup Incremental Build in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I want to set up an Incremental Build in TFS as we want to deploy only modified files into Physical path, not the entire code.

We want the feature to build & deploy only the files that have been changed from the previous deployment. This will reduce the build and deployment time and the developers won't have to wait longer to see their changes deployed.

Comment: I'm quite sure you need to explain what you're building and how -- maybe also the details like how long the builds now take and what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is not an "incremental build". You a describing a much more complex situation than an incremental build.

What you're describing has never been an out-of-the-box option, and is in fact incredibly difficult to do properly, and ultimately would probably not impact things as much as you're hoping, anyway.

First of all, it's actually **very difficult** to determine a subset of files that have changed between deployments. And if you're building and deploying properly, then you're making a single build and deploying it along a pipeline of environments. This means that "what's different" at any given time is potentially different for every environment in your pipeline. Ex: DEV has version 5, QA has version 4, and PROD has version 3. So you have to start by assuming that you're going to use the oldest version. Build systems have no innate knowledge of "releases", so you'd have to build something into your build and release pipelines to track what source version constitutes the latest code in production.

Let's say you've solved that problem. You now have the ability to retrieve just the delta between what's deployed to production and the commit being built.

If you're working with compiled code, then you still need all of the source code, because you're going to have to rebuild the whole thing. Every assembly is going to get regenerated, and different metadata at compilation time is going to mean those assemblies are different even if the code that constitutes those assemblies is the same. And since assemblies can reference other assemblies, you have no straightforward way of determining at build time which assemblies have actually changed and need to be deployed. So you pretty much have no choice but to deploy all compiled assets every time. Note that this still applies to TypeScript or anything else that goes through a compiler/transpiler process; you need all of the code available, and it has to go through the entire build process.

So at this point, you still have to build your entire application to get the deployable output. Build time hasn't gone down at all. You've managed to bring down just a subset of static content (i.e. HTML pages, images, etc) to be deployed, though. That may have sped your deployments up a bit!

However, if the thing that's making your build and deployment process slow is that you have a ton of non-code-related static content, then you've gone through a very long and convoluted process to arrive at a much simpler solution: **Move static content to a CDN** and get it out of source control, or have a separate process that manages static content so that it can be deployed independently of unrelated application code.

You haven't really provided any information that can be used to provide a recommendation on how to proceed, but hopefully this answer is helpful in understanding why what you want to do is not going to solve your problem, unless you are dealing entirely with static content or scripts that don't require building.